# I am unable to access weblogic admin server console

Tags: weblogic11g

I am not able to access Weblogic admin console, but it was accessible before and installed application inside the server is working. I have restarted  server but it’s not working. Can you please help me to resolve the issue if any so that I can access the admin console….

Answer (score 1):

If the console login page is not accessible at all then it sounds like you need to start the admin server service. You can do this on Windows by going to start-->All Programs-->Oracle Classic instance-->Start Weblogic Admin Server. Give this about 20 - 30 seconds the start up then try again.

Regards,
Vect0r